# ¿Como contar registros de una BD con php?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, count

A ver, es primera vez que publico acá, y también es primera vez que realizo esta acción en un sistema.

Supongo que es algo bastante sencillo, hago una consulta a la BD, de momento quiero obtener el total de Lineas telefónicas para luego mostrar esta cantidad en pantalla. Intento hacerlo con la funcion Count() pero solo me muestra el mensaje:

Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\laragon\www\teletest\index.php on line 13
Array

```
$sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_lineas");
$sentencia->execute();
$lista_tbl_lineas=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $lista_tbl_lineas;
```

Comment: Intenta con [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero: **fetchAll()** devuelve un array, de ahí que te dé error al tratar de utilizar **echo**.

Tienes dos opciones:

```
// Si sólo vas a necesitar el total de filas, como sugería Sal
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_lineas");
$sentencia->execute();
echo $sentencia->fetchColumn();

// Si quieres obtener a la vez un conjunto de datos y, además, el número total de filas
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_lineas");
$sentencia->execute();
$datos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $sentencia->rowCount();
```

Comment: Muy ineficiente; así provocas una lectura completa de la tabla cuando únicamente quieres el conteo de registros. *"Maestra: saque a todos los alumnos del salón para que pueda contarlos"*. Cuando la maestra bien sabe y puede decir cuántos alumnos tiene.

Comment: Seguramente en este caso es así, pero en muchos casos y siguiendo el ejemplo de la profesora, además de saber el número de alumnos es posible que se necesite saber sus nombres. Hay muchísimos casos donde el total acompaña a un conjunto de datos, por eso es bueno conocer la existencia de mysqli_num_rows, ya que, precisamente en pos de la eficiencia, evitará tener que hacer dos consultas (una para los datos de los alumnos y otra para saber cuántos hay).

Comment: Intenté con la sugerencia que me propones y obtuve lo siguiente.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::store_result() in C:\laragon\www\teletest\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\teletest\index.php on line 11`

Comment: He corregido la respuesta, con PDO se utiliza  rowCount(), no num_rows. Además, he incluido en la respuesta la opción que plantea Sal. Espero que te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar la función var_dump() en lugar de utilizar echo

lo que te dice php es que no puede mostrar los datos de un array u Objeto con la
sentencia   echo

entonces deberías hacerlo así

var_dump($lista_tbl_lineas);

saludos

Comment: Lo he intentado de esta manera pero el Var_dump() me muestra el array completo:

**array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> int(38) } }**

En realidad necesitaria solo el total.

Answer (score 0):

Perdona , pensé que querrías ver que datos venían  en la respuesta.

Los comentarios de los amigos antes también son validos.

Pero podrías hacerlo así.

```
          $lista_tbl_lineas=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   

          echo $lista_tbl_lineas[0];
```

o si quieres asociarlo a una variable para usarlo mas adelante.

```
          $lista = $lista_tbl_lineas[0];
```